# Can whatnot be used as a question word?

Tags: word-usage, questions

I have searched Internet but have found no such point.It is mentioned that it is used at the end of the sentence.

Can "whatnot" be used as a question word like:

Whatnot is found in this shop?

Comment: Did you check [whatnot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whatnot) in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. *Whatnot* is one of those nouns we use for unspecified objects, in the sense of 'other things of that kind'. It is also the name of an old-fashioned item of furniture; a small stand for ornaments that people sometimes used to have in their living-rooms.